# R5RS Spec letrec example for eqv?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm reading the spec for R5RS and it have this two examples for `eqv?`

```
(letrec ((f (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'both 'f)))
         (g (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'both 'g))))
  (eqv? f g))
                               ;; ===>  unspecified

(letrec ((f (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'f 'both)))
         (g (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'g 'both))))
  (eqv? f g))
                               ;; ===>  #f
```

I don't understand this is it be error in code, from me it looks like they compare function objects that are different they are two lambda expressions, does it mean that first example some how can return true if it's unspecified becuase of optimization? Shouldn't it be reversed? unspecified for `(if (eqv? f g) 'f 'both)` that both functions return same symbol.

[Spec link](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a remarkably subtle example.  In the first example:

```
(letrec ((f (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'both 'f)))
         (g (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'both 'g))))
  (eqv? f g))
```

Well, `f` and `g` are textually different, right?  So this should be false.  Except that, well, if we *assume* that `(eqv? f g)` is true – we assume that `f` and `g` *are* the same in fact – then we could optimize away the conditionals, and rewrite each of `f` and `g` to:

```
(letrec ((f (lambda () 'both))
         (g (lambda () 'both)))
  (eqv? f g))
```

And now, well, we could optimize them into the same function, as considered by `eqv?`.  So the assumption that the functions are the same as considered by `eqv?` leads us to a state where they could be optimized to actually *be* equivalent under `eqv?`.

In the second example:

```
(letrec ((f (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'f 'both)))
         (g (lambda () (if (eqv? f g) 'g 'both))))
  (eqv? f g))
```

Well, if we again assume that `f` and `g` are the same, then we can try to optimise the conditionals away again:

```
(letrec ((f (lambda () 'f))
         (g (lambda () 'g)))
  (eqv? f g))
```

And this is, obviously, false.  So we *can't* assume `f` and `g` are the same.  And now we have trouble, because if we assume they are *different* then we could perhaps optimize them again ... and now they're the same function and perhaps could be optimized to be the same under `eqv?` ... except now we're in a loop.  So they must be considered to be different under `eqv?`, even though they may return the same value.

The second example is very close to the liar's paradox: it escapes because `eqv?` is allowed to not know that two things are the same (for a definition of 'the same' which I'd have to think about harder) even though they actually are.

---

Personal note: while I think these examples are extremely clever and subtle, I would not have put them in a spec, or at least not without a very detailed explanation of what the system is, or is not, allowed to do, and why.